# Arcade Attribute Rules on joined feature layers (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcade

I have a series of attribute rules defined.  The various fields are referenced using `$feature.<fieldname>`.  I know my rules are valid and well defined because they work fine as long as the feature class is edited on its own. I can successfully edit both as individual features via the attribute editor and with the CalculateField tool.

As soon as I join the feature class to another layer and attempt to use the CalculateField tool I get a 'Field not found' error.  I am guessing this is related to the fact that the attribute can't find `$feature.<fieldname>` in a joined table.  If I manually attempt to calculate a field on the same joined table the arcade syntax switches to `$feature['<tablename>.<fieldname>']` - however this syntax does not appear to work when the feature class is edited on its own.

Is there a syntax that will work both with a standalone feature class and when participating in a join ?